# Как процитировать два полный предложения в одном?

Tags: цитата

Правильно ли здесь то, что второе цитируемое предложение с большой буквы ("Для выполнения плана...") или так нельзя делать?

> Но также В.П. Аксёнов описывает поступки его коллеги, Макара
>   Ивановича: «В райздраве он славился лихостью своих диагнозов», «Для
>   выполнения плана койко-дней Макар Иванович клал в больницу знакомых
>   старушек и упражнялся на них в диагностике».

Comment: я не понимаю, почему вы считаете, что это вопрос про русский язык.

Comment: я бы и первое с большой буквы не начинал

Comment: @shabunc , а про какой язык, по вашему, вопрос?

Comment: @Яна_Крылова , большой вопрос, нужны ли вообще кавычки в вашем примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the quotations should start with the capital letters, assumed that they start with the capital letters in the quoted text.

You should also use semicolons to separate them, not commas.

Lopatin, *Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации*, § 147

> При перечислении примеров точка после закрывающей скобки заменяется на точку с запятой: *«Как ты таинственна, гроза!» (И. Бунин. Полями пахнет...); «Не покидайте своих возлюбленных. Былых возлюбленных на свете нет...» (А. Вознесенский. Поэмы. М., 2001. С. 5).*

Technically, the rules tells about references in parentheses, but it also applies to bare quotations.

I also have a strong feeling that you meant *так же* ("in the same way"), not *также* ("also").

> Но так же В. П. Аксёнов описывает поступки его коллеги, Макара Ивановича: «В райздраве он славился лихостью своих диагнозов»; «Для выполнения плана койко-дней Макар Иванович клал в больницу знакомых старушек и упражнялся на них в диагностике».